# append or extend using Lambda in Python

Tags: python, lambda

I want to do this:

```
def my_func(x):
    x.extend('\n')
    return x

var1 = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]

for item in var1:
    var2 = my_func(item)
    print(var2)
>>>
['a', 'b', '\n']
['c', 'd', '\n']
```

using Lambda function. When I try

```
var1 = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
var_x = list(map(lambda x: x.extend('\n'), var1))
>>>
[None, None]
```

How to write it then???

Comment: what does this index mean in this context?

Answer (score 4):

`extend` mutates the `list` in-place and returns `None`. You should try to use something like:

```
x + ['\n']
```

instead of:

```
x.extend('\n')
```

Comment: but the question is about *using a `lambda` function` to `extend`. You could incorporate your idea (`x + ['\n']`) in a `lambda`.

Comment: x + ['\n'] returns x with appended '\n', whereas x.extend('\n') mutates the object and doesn't return anything (hence None).

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand **the why**, but here is **the how**:

```
var1 = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]

f = lambda x: list(map(lambda y: y.extend('\n'), x))

var2 = f(var1)
print(var1)  # [['a', 'b', '\n'], ['c', 'd', '\n']]
```

---

Or , if you want to keep the `for`-loop:

```
var1 = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]

f = lambda x: x + ['\n']

for sublist in var1:
  var2 = f(sublist)
  print(var2)

# ['a', 'b', '\n']
# ['c', 'd', '\n']
```

Comment: thnx, I am learning. Isn't this code with lambdas shorter and more readable?

Comment: shorter it might be, but as far as readability is concerned I would say, *no*. Although this depends on how familiar one is with `lambda`-structures

Comment: yes true, thnx.
By any chance, maybe you happen to know any brief and clear explanation or a video of what happens behind the curtains with variables, mutations and allocations to memory?

Comment: by the way, the first function returns: [None, None]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extend a list within a lambda (one valid case for this would be if you have several lists and want to `reduce` them to one cumulative list), you could use the following lambda:

```
lambda accum, chunk: (accum.extend(chunk), accum)[1]
```

This would be creating a temporary tuple of `(None, accum)`, but since `list.extend` is a mutating operation you'd actually get what you need.

In your particular case, the code would be like this:

```
var1 = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
var_x = list(map(lambda x: (x.extend('\n'), x)[1], var1))
```